# Snake with red eyes and black skin found in a plant pot

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

It was found dead/stiff in an empty plant pot in a kitchen.

[image] [image]

Could it be a young *Höllenotter* (a melanistic [vipera berus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus), [photo in Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hugorme.jpg))?

Is the reddish/brownish part an injury? And what are the greyish parts (especially at the snout)?

#### Size (only estimated)

Diameter: 2.2 cm
Length (in this rolled-up state): 10–12 cm

#### Location

Western Germany.

In the kitchen were three plants pots in a row that were used for culinary herbs, one still had basil, the other two were empty for some time. It’s unknown if the snake was already there when the pot was emptied.

Comment: Are there any pictures, which are not out of focus? Or maybe a close-up of the head?

Comment: @JulPal: Unfortunately not, this is all what I’ve got (I didn’t make the photos).

Comment: For me it looks more like a leech or a worm than a snake. a better pic of the head would be more useful.